# Obtaining wrong result when using PyFloat_FromDouble in a C function called from Python

Tags: python, c, arrays

I am in the process of learning how to call C functions from Python by making wrappers. My final goal is to pass huge complex arrays declared in Python to my C functions and get back other huge complex arrays.

I have started with an easy example in order to understand the basics of calling C functions from Python. I have defined a function that reads an array of double (any size) and gives back the sum over all the values. Here is my wrapperTest.c code:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *sumArray(PyObject * self, PyObject * args){
    PyObject *ret;

    PyObject* myTuple;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &myTuple)) return NULL;

    printf("PyTuple_Size=%ld\n", PyTuple_Size(myTuple));

    double *my_array;
    my_array=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*PyTuple_Size(myTuple));

    int tupleSize;
    tupleSize=PyTuple_Size(myTuple);

    int i;
    PyObject* tupleItem;
    for(i=0; i<tupleSize; i++){
        tupleItem=PyTuple_GetItem(myTuple, i);

        if(!PyFloat_Check(tupleItem)){
            printf("Error: tuple contains a non-float value");
            exit(1);
        }
        my_array[i]=PyFloat_AsDouble(tupleItem);
        printf("my_array[%d]=%lf\n", i, my_array[i]);
    }

    double result;
    result=0.;
    for(i=0; i<tupleSize; i++){
        result+=my_array[i];
    }
    printf("result=%lf\n", result);

    ret=PyFloat_FromDouble(result);

    free(my_array);

    return ret;
}

static PyMethodDef wrapperTest_funcs[] = {
    {"sumArray", (PyCFunction)sumArray,
        METH_VARARGS, ""},
    {NULL}
};

void initwrapperTest(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("wrapperTest", wrapperTest_funcs,
                   "Extension module example!");
}
```

I can successfully compile the extension by running the script setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='wrapperTest', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('wrapperTest', ['wrapperTest.c'])])
```

using the command "python setup.py install". Moreover, I am able to import the extension while running Python and execute the function. However, I am not able to get always a correct result from my defined function. For instance, if I try to pass the array a=(1.2, 2.4), this is what I get:

```
>>> import wrapperTest
>>> a=(1.2, 2.4)
>>> b=wrapperTest.sumArray(a)
PyTuple_Size=2
my_array[0]=1.200000
my_array[1]=2.400000
result=3.600000
>>> b 
3.5999999999999996
```

Clearly the correct result is 3.6 (the one printed by the function written in C), but the final result obtained in Python is 3.5999999999999996. Of course it is very close to the correct result, but not the same. What am I missing?

Comment: "Clearly the correct result is 3.6" - sounds like you need to [read up about floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I did not know about this fact. At least this means that my wrapper is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default precision for printf output is I think 6 decimal places.

Could it be just that your printf function is rounding the answer to 3.600000 and python is being more accurate in it's printing?

Comment: Correct. CPython uses code by David Gay to get the *shortest* round-tripping representation. C's standard library doesn't contain such an algorithm but one can use `"%.17g"` (or `"%.*g"` and `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` for portability) to achieve at least round-tripping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I did not know about this fact. At least this means that my wrapper is correct!